# inet_ntop() prints D04.204.204.204

Tags: c

I'm trying some usage of inet_ntop, but it prints like "?4.204.204.204"(? can be random), which is obviously not an IP address. So I searched from net a bit, but almost every post is about LINUX and use different header with me. Do I need more or did I write some wrong code?
I am coding with WINDOWS.
And I hope to know WHY this doesn't work

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32")
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>


void main()
{
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct in_addr in;
    char buff[20];
    char* pbuff =buff;

    *pbuff = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &in.s_addr, buff, sizeof(buff));

    printf("%s", pbuff);
}
```

Comment: Would that be because you overwrote the first char by writing `*pbuff =`?